# How Can I have a shared inventory for my store views but alter product status for each view

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I am creating some multiple country stores, the inventory is managed from one location.

All stores will have the some of the products in common but not all stores will have all of the products for sale.

For example the UK store will have 100% of products sold but the FR store will have 40% of the products sold

I need to stop the other 60% of the UK products showing up in the FR store.

I would like to keep a common inventory hence the use of the store views otherwise I would run into complications managing the total inventory.

Is there a way to do this?